# XPath: Can I select a node whose next (or previous) sibling matches some criteria?

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am reformatting an HTML document using the Agility Pack, and I've run into a limitation of my understanding of XPath.

In the document I'm working with, the following is a common construct:

> 128<sup>2</sup>

Which is built like this:

```
128<img src="" style="display: none;" alt="^(" /><sup>2</sup><img src="" style="display: none;" alt=")" />
```

So, when you select that and copy it to the clipboard it turns into:

> 128^(2)

Now, I would like to use XPath to remove these `img` tags.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//img[@alt='^('  ???/sup]
```

**How do I select an element based on existence of an immediate sibling?**

Comment: Is removing images based solely on their alt text not sufficient? Are there any image tags with an alt text of ")" that you want to keep?

Comment: Potentially, yeah.  I'm formatting this for the Kindle.  I know that the Kindle supports the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags, but `alt=")"` could be used on something else that isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently it is something like this:

```
//img[@alt='^(' and following-sibling::*[1][self::sup]]
```

---

That is (and, I'm guessing, here):

```
//img
```

An `img` (anywhere)...

```
[@alt='^(' and  ...  ]
```

... whose `alt` attribute is `'^('` and ...

```
following-sibling::*[1]
```

... whose first following sibling ...

```
[self::sup]
```

... can call itself a `sup`.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, make it a compound condition.  Something like:

```
//img[@alt='^('  ???/sup AND preceding-sibling::*[1] AND following-sibling::*[1]]
```